# Add a column with count and sum by specific group in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
Dataset_1

   Date   Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Metric_A    Metric_B
10/1/19   NULL   NULL   NULL      A         10        NULL
10/1/19   NULL   NULL     AB      A       NULL          70
10/1/19   NULL   NULL   NULL      B         60        NULL
10/2/19   NULL      A     AC      B        100        NULL
```

How do I get the count by group (Date, Var1, Var2, Var4) and the sum of Metric A by the same group as a separate column without changing the column structure? I just want to add these two columns to the end of my current dataset

My expected output is below:

```
   Date   Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Metric_A    Metric_B   COUNT_Var   SUM_A
10/1/19   NULL   NULL   NULL      A         10        NULL           2      10
10/1/19   NULL   NULL     AB      A       NULL          70           2      10
10/1/19   NULL   NULL   NULL      B         60        NULL           1      60
10/2/19   NULL      A     AC      B        100        NULL           1     100
```

My attempt was going to be below but it didn't work:

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Var1, Var2, Var4), 
SUM(A) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Var1, Var2, Var4) 
FROM Dataset_1
```

Comment: What results do you get by your query?

Comment: I just answered my own question lol, I don't know why this didn't work the first time. The above query is correct, apologies

Answer (score 1):

From your data, `var4` is defining the groups and nothing else:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Var4), 
       SUM(A) OVER (PARTITION BY Var4) 
FROM Dataset_1 d
```

Comment: In the last 2 rows of the OP's sample data Var4 = 'B', but the dates are different.

Comment: @forpas . . . I don't see what the date has to do with it.  The counts are the same on the last two rows.